# One task with multiple threading and different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, multithreading

I'm still facing problems with multithreading on iOS. Basically what I want to do is to fetch json in MainViewController (when app launches) and then populate left menu (SWRevealViewController) with this data.

But let's consider situation with LOW internet speed, when user reveals menu and the data didn't come from MainViewController. Obviously I'm fetching JSON from both controllers. I don't know how to make it that Sidebar will wait for that data until MainViewController finishes fetching?

Call from *MainViewController*

```
[[CategoriesStore sharedStore] fetchDataWithCallback:^(NSArray *allCategories, NSError* error) {

}];
```

Call from *SidebarViewController* inside async blocks

```
[[CategoriesStore sharedStore] fetchDataWithCallback:^(NSArray *allCategories, NSError* error) {
    if (error) {
    } else {
        //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
        blockSafe.allDirectories = allCategories;
        [blockSafe.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}];
```

Fetching json from *CategoriesStore* (singleton model)

```
+(instancetype)sharedStore {
static CategoriesStore *sharedStore = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];


});

return sharedStore;

}

- (instancetype)initPrivate {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    [self sessionConf];
    _allCategories = nil;
}

return self;
}

- (void)fetchDataWithCallback:(void(^)(NSArray *allCategories, NSError* error))callback {
NSLog(@"CategoriesStore - %@",self.description);
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!_allCategories) {
        NSURLSessionDataTask *getCategories =
        [self.session dataTaskWithURL:categoriesURL
                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                        NSURLResponse *response,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"error - %@",error.localizedDescription);
                            callback(nil, error);
                            return;
                        }

                        NSError *jsonError = nil;

                        NSArray *json =
                        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:&jsonError];
                        if (!jsonError) {
                            _allCategories = json;
                            NSLog(@"categories fetched");
                            callback(_allCategories, nil);
                        } else {
                            callback(nil, jsonError);
                        }
                    }];

        [getCategories resume];
    } else {
        callback(_allCategories,nil);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help and advices!

Comment: Anyone? Please. I bet it's something easy and tricky to do. Another solution is to callback Sidebar View Controller but it doesn't work with SWRevealController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix" this problem is that I used SWRevealViewController *rearViewController* property.

When I set up my sidebar to reveal in MainViewController (so in delegate) there's callback to fetchJSON.

```
-(void)sideBarSetup {
    ....... your initialization for RevealSideBar........
    [self fetchJSON];
}
```

Body for fetchJSON

```
-(void)fetchJSON {
    SidebarViewController *svc = (SidebarViewController *)self.revealViewController.rearViewController;
    [svc fetchAll];
}
```

Then in SidebarViewController.

```
dispatch_group_t fetchingGroup = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(fetchingGroup);

[[CategoriesStore sharedStore] fetchDataWithCallback:^(NSArray *allCategories, NSError* error) {
    if (error) {
        // handle error here
    } else {
        blockSafe.allDirectories = allCategories;
        [blockSafe.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}];

[[LinksStore sharedStore] fetchDataWithCallback:^(NSArray *allLinks, NSError* error) {
    if (error) {
        // handle error here
    } else {
        blockSafe.allLinks = allLinks;
        [blockSafe.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}];

dispatch_group_leave(fetchingGroup);

dispatch_group_notify(fetchingGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
});
```

Of course you have to add method to interface in your header class file.

It's impossible in this case to pass data through initialization of SidebarViewController class, because property rearViewController has own reference to this controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:
        dispatch_group_t group_t = dispatch_group_create();

```
    dispatch_group_async(group_t, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //do the first thing
    });

    dispatch_group_async(group_t, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //do the second thing
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group_t, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update UI
    });
```

Comment: Thank's for reply @Burning but it won't work on different ViewControllers (classes)